# Why can't T be deduced from Class<T>::MemberClass?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

In the following mcve:

```
template <typename T> class Class { public: class MemberClass {}; };

#include <list>

template <typename T>
Class<T> func(const typename Class<T>::MemberClass& start, 
              const typename Class<T>::MemberClass& finish)
{
    Class<T> result; return result;
}

int main ()
{
    Class<int>::MemberClass i, j;
    Class<int> L2; L2 = func(i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

I find that the compiler does not recognize the function as something that can take the given arguments. In Visual Studio the error is

```
1>C:\...\main.cpp(15,25): error C2672: 'func': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\...\main.cpp(15,34): error C2783: 'Class<T> func(const Class<T>::MemberClass &,const Class<T>::MemberClass &)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
1>C:\...\main.cpp(6): message : see declaration of 'func'
```

In g++, here are the errors:

```
main.cpp:15:34: error: no matching function for call to 'func(Class<int>::MemberClass&, Class<int>::MemberClass&)'
   15 |     Class<int> L2; L2 = func(i, j);
      |                                  ^
main.cpp:6:10: note: candidate: 'template<class T> Class<T> func(const typename Class<T>::MemberClass&, const typename Class<T>::MemberClass&)'
    6 | Class<T> func(const typename Class<T>::MemberClass& start,
      |          ^~~~
main.cpp:6:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:15:34: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   15 |     Class<int> L2; L2 = func(i, j);
      |                                  ^                                     ^
```

I'm sure there's another way to write the function (it could return a MemberClass not a Class), but, well, this should be doable. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Calling the function with `func<int>` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/jfEoEbe7b).

Comment: I think the problem is that that actually `MemberClass` is independent of `T` so it fails to deduct the template argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite literally, every possible T that matches your Class has a MemberClass type.  The compiler is not going to look inside all of them to find a match, because it'd have to instantiate templates just to see their contents, and it would potentially match too many things.  So the langauge simply doesn't look inside like that.

The way you can solve this is to tell the compiler what `T` is when you call it, here, providing an explicit `int` template argument:

```
func<int>(i, j);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it without specifying a template type for `func`, you can make the type of `Class<T>` known to the `MemberClass` and have the compiler resolve `T` within the `func` function template to `Class<T>::MemberClass` instead of the `T` within `Class<T>`.

This is very easy for the compiler, since it is the type of the arguments of `func`:

```
template <typename T> 
class Class { 
public: 
  class MemberClass { public: using ParentClass = Class<T>; }; 
};

#include <list>

template <typename T>
typename T::ParentClass func(const T& start, 
                             const T& finish)
{
    typename T::ParentClass result; return result;
}

int main ()
{
    Class<int>::MemberClass i, j;
    Class<int> L2; L2 = func(i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
template <typename T>
Class<T> func(const typename Class<T>::MemberClass&, 
              const typename Class<T>::MemberClass&);
```

`T` is not deducible (left of `::`).

You have several options:

- Make a friend non-template function inside `MemberClass` (will be found by ADL):

  ```
  template <typename T> class Class {
  public:
      class MemberClass {
          friend Class func(const MemberClass& start, const MemberClass& finish)
          {
              Class result; return result;
          } 
      };
  };
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b31x95ecq)
- Be more generic of accepted type (you need here to give a way to retrieve `Class` from `MemberClass`):

  ```
  template <typename T> class Class {
  public:
      class MemberClass {
      public:
          using ParentClass = Class;
      };
  };

  template <typename T>
  typename T::ParentClass func(const T& start, const T& finish)
  {
      typename T::ParentClass result; return result;
  }
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rd7bTGcTP)